# What's the template command to print available tokens?

Tags: templating, debugging

I'm trying to dump a list of available template tokens, and their contents. There's a command that's available in dev mode, but I haven't found it's documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick `{{ dump(_context) }}` in a template file to print out all the available values.

`{{ dump(_context|keys) }}` Outputs the keys of the array without going through it recursively.

Comment: An addendum, the craft_kint plugin, [github.com/mildlygeeky/craft_kint](https://github.com/mildlygeeky/craft_kint), lets you use `{{ d{_context) }}` and makes the output much friendlier. Collapsible, colorful, and the like.